# use beacon wake up APP in the background to scan BLE - IOS

Tags: ios, bluetooth, scanning, beacon

I want use ibeacon wake up theAPP in the background to scan the bluetooth ,I wake up APP already successfully, but after execution to scan,but  discover cannot perform,What should I do
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SefNO.jpg)
When the APP use ibeacon awaken to this step ,and continuously perform it

```
manager.scanForPeripheralsWithServices([CBUUID(string: "6600")], options: [CBCentralManagerScanOptionAllowDuplicatesKey: true])
```

but can't perform this step

```
centralManager(central: CBCentralManager, didDiscoverPeripheral peripheral: CBPeripheral, advertisementData: [String : AnyObject], RSSI: NSNumber)
```

Comment: Can you show some code?

Comment: When performing this step manager.scanForPeripheralsWithServices([CBUUID(string: "6600")], options: [CBCentralManagerScanOptionAllowDuplicatesKey: true])
    }
No longer behind the execution
    func centralManager(central: CBCentralManager, didDiscoverPeripheral peripheral: CBPeripheral, advertisementData: [String : AnyObject], RSSI: NSNumber) { }

Comment: please *edit* your question to include your code so that it can be formatted correctly

Comment: sorry，i'm don't know how to use the code format

Comment: Just put the code in the question and put 4 spaces (or more) in front of each line

Comment: use language to introduce it, can I use my ibeacon awakens the APP, and execute the code, but after executing the sacn does not perform didDiscoverPeripheral method

Comment: How do you create your `CBCentralManager`?  is `manager` a property or local variable?  Also `allow duplicates = true` is ineffective in the background. You can only use this option when you are scanning in the foreground

Comment: self.manager = CBCentralManager(delegate: self, queue: dispatch_get_main_queue())   global variable   i know options is ignore ,the background Settings has been done,but xecution will not execute discover after scan

Comment: Does your code discover the device if you scan in the foreground?

Comment: ibeacon advertise & BLE advertise will there be a conflict ?

Comment: That depends on your device - can it advertise as a peripheral and a beacon at the same time?

Comment: when in the foreground everything is all right

Comment: Please put code in your question, not screen shots.  Please add more code.  Show your `didEnterRegion` function and how it starts scanning for peripherals

Comment: Is your CBCentralManager delegate set?  Try getting rid of the `dispatch_async` - there is no need for it

Comment: CBCentralManager delegate already set，'dispatch_async' should be no impact

Comment: Perhaps, but you have limited execution time in the background.  Since you haven't initiated a long-running background task, there is a chance that your app will be suspended as soon as the region delegate function returns and before the scan is dispatched.  The async dispatch is unnecessary so I would get rid of it

Comment: Can you help me write ibeacon&BLE need to set up and attention points out, I refer to one by one

Comment: Performed in the background to scan, but after a few seconds to open the APP will execute discover

Comment: Are you on iOS 10?  Do you have an device on an older OS version to test on?

Comment: iOS 9.2  iphone5s&ipad mini2 iOS 9.3